# How many draws to get 50% chance of drawing red marble

Tags: probability, probability-theory

You have a box of 98 blue marbles and 2 red marbles, and you pick randomly with replacement. How many draws will it take for there to be a better than 50% chance for a red marble to appear at least once?

Comment: Hint : calculate the probability of NOT picking a red, and view when this probability is below 50%

Comment: So would it be something along the lines of $.5 = 1 - .98^n$? Which gets you 35 draws?

Comment: Solve your equation for $n$ to get $n = 34.3096$, so 35 draws.

Comment: This problem would also be interesting (and solvable) if drawing without replacement.

Comment: @GregMartin It is solvable in it's current state as well. But I do agree in the "more interesting" part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chance of NOT drawing a red marble is 49/50. So the chance of not drawing a red marble n times in a row, is (49/50)^n.

Since you do want to draw a red marble, you want the chance of drawing no reds (essentially the same as drawing n non-reds in a row out of n draws) to be less than 50%.

So we can put up an equation:

0.5=(49/50)^n, solve for n.

We get approximately 34.3

We will round that number *up*, because rounding down would bring the chances of not drawing a red over 0.5

So the answer is 35 marbles

Comment: That's wrong. By this reasoning, the chance of drawing a red marble would at some point exceed $1$.

Comment: @joriki Fixed now